# Skip first line header and match on second

Tags: regex

The following regular expression needs to get the second line of the output below, however its matches on the first. How do I skip `error code|error text|submission reference` and match on  `0|sms submitted|eb725f96b4b094d5f8318741cc1a545f-2`

Expression

```
(?P<status_code>[0-9]+)|(?P<status_message>.+)|(?P<gateway_message_id>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)
```

Text

```
error code|error text|submission reference
0|sms submitted|eb725f96b4b094d5f8318741cc1a545f-2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must escape `|` symbols as they have special meaning in regular expressions. With such expression your first line wouln't be matched:

```
(?P<status_code>[0-9]+)\|(?P<status_message>.+)\|(?P<gateway_message_id>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)
```

Without escaping that symbol you are searching for `[0-9]+` *or* `.+` *or* `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+`. And then obviously `.+` matches the whole string. More about `|` you can read in [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

Comment: thanks for the response, but will this now match the Text above?

Comment: With that regexp you are able to find matching sequence, but it wouldn't match the whole string mentioned above. To match the whole string you should prepend it with `.*?`. I don't know what in what language you're using - you should probably also apply appropriate switch to regexp to handle new line characters.